How can I unclog a continuous drain in a portable air conditioner?
I bought a 10K SACC refurb Danby portable AC. It comes with a transparent draining hose, one drain opening at the bottom, and a 'continuous' opening in the middle.
Regretfully when using the middle continuous opening I get tank filled error in half an hour.
Bottom opening works fine but I have to put the conditioner on a stool to drain into a bucket. So cool air goes to the ceiling rather than at me, which is not ideal and exhaust hose is a bit stretched.
I found few ideas on internet, but would like hear expert opinions to minimize risks and potential damage to the unit and apartment.
I have already tried to blow air in with hose and mouth which did not work. I am afraid to suck air out to get poisoned, it is a refurb and who know what solutions were tried before I got it.
I have neither air pump nor wet-dry vacuum. I have a canister one (Miele C3) and small stick vacuum. Maybe there is a way to use them somehow?
At the moment I think to try inject some vinegar into the opening with 5 cm3 surgical syringe.
What do you think?
I suspect chemicals or bleach would be more effective yet in the same time more risky for the apartment, furniture or the unit.
Update. After a few leak accidents I opted to return the unit

Vinegar is good for calcium/lime/similar build up/clogs.  Bleach is good for organics, but can stain/bleach some surfaces, vinegar also.  Drop cloths around will protect most stuff from spills, but 5cc is paper towel size.

I used a hand vacuum to suck out few remaining drops of water. The syringe is 5cc yet by using it multiple times I was able to pour  in about 50 ml or so via the hose (the diameter matches syringe) and blew some air in to sure that all vinegar got inside . I will try to run device in half an hour or so.

Some repeat vacuuming of both regular and continuous drain openings helped to fix the continuous drain feature.
Perhaps, injecting vinegar also contributed.
This particular unit also requires a little tilt forward to make continuous drain work.
While it is recommended to use a wet-dry shop vacuum (combined with peroxide or vinegar treatment), I only have regular household vacuums. So, I decided to pre-dry the unit and then vacuum it.

I gravity drained the AC unit by tilting it almost to 45 degrees (do not try alone unless very strong). Obviously, I unplugged the device before all these manipulations.

I used a hairdryer on high heat for 30 seconds, then pre-vacuumed the AC openings with a cheap bag-less hand vacuum with a washable HEPA filter and transparent canister/cyclone using a drain hose. A small, but not negligible, amount of water was extracted. The hose-to-vacuum connectors were fashioned from plastic bottles.

I plugged in the AC again and let it run in ventilator mode for a few hours to let it dry out.

Only then did I apply a powerful canister vacuum with a heavy dust bag for about two minutes, even though some experts believe that 1 minute is enough.


The continuous drain started working after that.
I did not try to disassemble the unit for further inspection, due to previous experiences with my dehumidifier cleaning.
Note: I do not have a strong attachment to either of my vacuums and have a spare old mid-size vacuum somewhere. Otherwise, it is best to invest in a decent wet-dry shop vacuum.
